# How can I use plot a box with data type datetime with panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
#Convert data type to continuous for these columns
for column in continuous_columns:
    df[column] = df[column].astype('datetime64')
```

```
cdc_case_earliest_dt       datetime64[ns]
cdc_report_dt              datetime64[ns]
pos_spec_dt                datetime64[ns]
onset_dt                   datetime64[ns]
```

```py
continuous_columns = df.select_dtypes(['datetime64']).columns 

# Plot a histogram summary sheet of the continuous features and save in a png file
df[continuous_columns].hist(layout=(6, 4), figsize=(30,30), bins=10)
plt.savefig('continuous_histograms_1-1.pdf')

for col in continuous_columns:
        f = df[col].plot(kind='box', figsize=(10,5), bins=10)
        plt.title(col)
        plt.ylabel('number of entries')
        plt.show()
```

My question is how can plot the box graph with data type datetime? It works for histogram `df[continuous_columns].hist` but fail in `df[col].plot` saying no numeric value.
I know it is related to data type but I am not sure how to change that it seem `.hist` can accept datetime as input but not plot.
Can somebody know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

for `.plot` method, it seems it cannot take the datetime datatype as input. What I did is convert it to int first.

```py
df_unix_sec = df['cdc_case_earliest_dt'].astype(int)
```